How to Efficiently Manage and Localize Time Zone Data for a WordPress Plugin
I'm developing a WordPress plugin called "My Nutrition Tracker" which allows gym members to track their daily food intake and calories. The plugin stores the date and time of each entry based on the server's default timezone.
Here's a snippet:
function mnt_handle_form_submission() {
    if (isset($_POST['mnt_submit'])) {
        
        $food_item = $_POST['food_item'];
        $calories = intval($_POST['calories']);
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'nutrition_tracker';

        $wpdb->insert($table_name,
            array('food_item' => $food_item, 'calories' => $calories, 'date' => current_time('mysql')),
            array('%s','%d','%s')
        );
    }
}


How can I modify the plugin to automatically adjust and display the date and time entries according to each user's local time zone?
